# Mysql table with bootstrap responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to get my html/php mysql table in my website to be more responsive so I integrated bootstrap to it, but after I had done that and added what i needed from Bootstrap it wouldn't be responsive at all. So when I am looking at my table on my desktop it fits the whole screen, but if I try to use it on my Nexus 6 phone it is simply to big and it is hard to see the information the table has, becuase you have to scroll alot and wont change size even if I resize the browser on my desktop.

Code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Domene informasjon</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- JQuery og Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">

            <?php
            if(!isset($_GET['field'])) $field = 'ID'; else $field = $_GET['field'];
            if(!isset($_GET['sorting'])) $sort = 'ASC'; else $sort = $_GET['sorting'];

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM server1 ORDER BY " .$field." ".$sort;

          if($sort == 'ASC') $sort = 'DESC'; else $sort = 'ASC';
          ?>

<table id="sorting_table" class="table table-bordered">

 <tr>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=ID">ID</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Vsite">Vsite</th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Registrar">Registrar</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Eier">Eier</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=NS">NS</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=A">A</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=MX">MX</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Flyttet">Flyttet</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Slettet">Slettet</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Delt">Delt</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Behkd">Behkd</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Varenr">Varenr</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Server">Server</a></th>
  <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Sistoppdatert">Sist oppdatert</a></th>
</tr>

<?php
// kobling til databasen
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "ascent") or die (mysql_error ());

//merke databasen
mysql_select_db("dom_oversikt") or die(mysql_error());

//kjøring av query
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

//kvar rad blir til en tabbel
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

$color = '';

if ( ($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "JA") && ($row['Delt'] == "NEI") ) $color ='#ff0000';
if ( (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "JA"))|| (($row['Flyttet'] == "JA") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "JA")) ) $color ='#FFFF00';
if ( ($row['Flyttet'] == "JA") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "NEI") ) $color ='#1E90FF';
if ( (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "JA")) || (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "NEI")) ) $color ='#3CB371';

    //Første kolone som skal vises
    echo '<tr style="background-color: '. $color . '">';
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['ID']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Vsite']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Registrar']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Eier']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['NS']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['A']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['MX']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Flyttet']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Slettet']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Delt']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Behkd']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Varenr']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Server']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Sistoppdatert']) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";


//stenge database koblingen
mysql_close();
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is really a CSS and HTML issue and has nothing to do with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Totally agree with @MagnusEriksson, you should consider using sample data in your table to stylish it, and then remove these fake data to integrate the php logic.

Comment: This isent about style, i am just trying to get it responsive with a output from mysql table

Comment: @Leifus - It is about style. Where the data comes from is irrelevant. You can't make PHP or MySQL responsive (that statement doesn't even makes sense). You get the data from MySQL with PHP. Then you render the table using PHP and as far as I can see, the markup looks OK. There's nothing you can do with MySQL or PHP that affects the responsiveness.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So the problem all along it that i use PHP?

Comment: No. My point was that your usage of PHP and MySQL was irrelevant to the question. :) Like @Zeratops said, use sample data (hard code) the table and content when designing. When you get everything to work, replace the hard coded sample data with the PHP-code. Easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code I have made the changes you need (you still have to download the plugin files and upload them to the server):

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Domene informasjon</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- added css restable plugin-->
    <link href="css/restable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- end plugin css-->
      <!-- JQuery og Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- added js restable plugin-->
    <script src="js/jquery.restable.js" type="text/javascript">
<!-- restable-->
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">

                <?php
                if(!isset($_GET['field'])) $field = 'ID'; else $field = $_GET['field'];
                if(!isset($_GET['sorting'])) $sort = 'ASC'; else $sort = $_GET['sorting'];

              $sql = "SELECT * FROM server1 ORDER BY " .$field." ".$sort;

              if($sort == 'ASC') $sort = 'DESC'; else $sort = 'ASC';
              ?>

    <table id="sorting_table" class="table table-bordered">

     <tr>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=ID">ID</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Vsite">Vsite</th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Registrar">Registrar</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Eier">Eier</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=NS">NS</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=A">A</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=MX">MX</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Flyttet">Flyttet</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Slettet">Slettet</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Delt">Delt</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Behkd">Behkd</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Varenr">Varenr</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Server">Server</a></th>
      <th><a href="php.php?sorting=<?= $sort; ?>&field=Sistoppdatert">Sist oppdatert</a></th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    // kobling til databasen
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "ascent") or die (mysql_error ());

    //merke databasen
    mysql_select_db("dom_oversikt") or die(mysql_error());

    //kjøring av query
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);

    //kvar rad blir til en tabbel
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

    $color = '';

    if ( ($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "JA") && ($row['Delt'] == "NEI") ) $color ='#ff0000';
    if ( (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "JA"))|| (($row['Flyttet'] == "JA") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "JA")) ) $color ='#FFFF00';
    if ( ($row['Flyttet'] == "JA") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "NEI") ) $color ='#1E90FF';
    if ( (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "JA")) || (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "NEI")) ) $color ='#3CB371';

        //Første kolone som skal vises
        echo '<tr style="background-color: '. $color . '">';
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['ID']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Vsite']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Registrar']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Eier']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['NS']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['A']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['MX']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Flyttet']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Slettet']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Delt']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Behkd']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Varenr']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Server']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Sistoppdatert']) . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";


    //stenge database koblingen
    mysql_close();
    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--call the plugin-->
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#sorting_table').ReStable({
            rowHeaders: true, // Table has row headers?
            maxWidth: 480 // Size to which the table become responsive
        });
      })
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Oh, it works now, but with how much data i have in the table, you really have to scroll forever to get the info you want, but thanks anyway.

Comment: But In this way your table is mobile friendly. If you have large table you always will have this issue . But this is not a big problem. For large tables you need to implement some pagination so the user gets only a small set of data every time. And this is really easy to do.  Please if you find this useful don't forget to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Give your table the row headers!!! (I suppose you know how to do that)

Download this jquery plugin:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Lightweight-jQuery-Responsive-Table-Plugin-ReStable.html

Put this in your head tag AFTER jquery (this suppose that you upload those files in the css and js folder.)

```
<link href="css/jquery.restable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');<script src="js/jquery.restable.min.js"></script>'
```

Put this at the bottom of your page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
   $('#sorting_table').ReStable({
       rowHeaders: true, // if you want keep the row headers, else false. 
       maxWidth: 480 // Size to which the table become responsive
   });
});
```

You are done. Resize your browser and You will get a nice responsive table!

The advantage: For now on If you are working pretty much with tables you can make every table responsive with just three lines of code.

Comment: Then this mean i have no need for bootstrap anymore for my website, becuase i tryed to use that to make it responsive at first. @Franco

Comment: You can still use bootstrap to style your site. You can make with it all other html elements behave responsively, but you don't have to if you don't like it. And as I have alredy told you, please add the headers to your table! Don't also forget that bootstrap is a powerful component for your site. If you find that my answer is useful for you, please don't forget to accept it. Thank you. If you need any help just let me know.

Comment: I did what you worte i could do, but i cant see any diffrerance to what is was before  to be honest. With the responsivnes, any other ideas you have?@Franco

Comment: From the link I gave you, you need to download the plugin. Than you have to put in the head of your page 'jquery.restable.min.css' and 'jquery.restable.js'.  Did you do that?

Comment: For your convenience I have made a quick fiddle so you can see that this is working: https://jsfiddle.net/aqw59s6c/.  Go to the link and resize the browser.

Comment: The thing is that i have everything in 1 php document, and i am getting the information from a mysql database if that can be the problem? Like you can see above eveything is like that in 1 document.